# Swift: Variable used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I get the following compiling error:
"Variable 'self.entryData' used before being initialized"
How can I fix it and initialise the @state var entryData correctly in my init method?

```
struct EditEntryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var entryData: EditEntryData
    @ObservedObject var moneyEntry: MoneyEntry
    
    init(entry: MoneyEntry) {
        moneyEntry = entry
        let iOwe = entry.value < 0 ? true : false
        let value = abs(entry.value)
        
        
        entryData = EditEntryData(info: entry.infos, value: String(value), date: entry.date, iOwe: iOwe)
    }
}

struct EditEntryData {
    var info: String = ""
    var value: String = ""
    var date: Date = Date()
    var iOwe: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: What is EditEntryData? Can you please add here

Comment: EditEntryData is a simle struct. I added the structs definition to the question

Comment: You cannot initialise a `@State` variable in the initialiser. State is private to the view and needs to be initialised inline in the declaration, outside the initialiser: `@State var entryData =  EditEntryData(...)`. If you cannot do this, it's simply not "state". Put this value into a redesigned `@ObservedObject` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise state itself, like

```
    _entryData = State(initialValue: 
         EditEntryData(info: entry.infos, 
         value: String(value), date: entry.date, iOwe: iOwe))
```

Comment: A View is a function! This would create a new state variable whenever the view will be initialised, i.e. whenever it needs to be rendered. That would defeat the purpose of `@State` which is meant to manage state which is kept alive through several lifecycles, ie. calling the render function.